# Advice as to how to use Watir to drag items within a sortable class for automated tests

Tags: drag-and-drop, automated-tests, watir, jquery-ui-sortable

I need some advice as to how to use Watir to drag items within a ui-sortable class for automated tests.  We have several sortable classes on a page, and we can move items within or between these classes.  I can successfully automate the test to move an item between sortable classes, but not within a sortable class.

I can successfully pickup the element (using `browser.driver.action.click_and_hold(element)`),  but the problem comes in dropping the element after moving it.  When I drop the element (using `element.fire_event("onmouseup"`)), it's just dropping back into the old place.

I've tried moving the element by an amount, using `@browser.driver.action.move_by(400, 0)` and also tried moving to below another child element of the class `(@browser.driver.action.move_to(element2)`.

Neither work, and when I look at the DOM, the "placeholder" class for the class "ui-sortable-helper" hasn't moved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post link to the page, or a similar one.

Comment: Zeljko,  I'll need to get a page set up that I can give you access to.  The real page has authorisation on it, and so giving you this is not really possible.  Otherwise I can copy/paste out the HTML - would that work for you?

Comment: Any page where the problem can be reproduced is good enough.

Comment: I have got an example page in drop box https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s0z7lpgbx5eh0qo/0XxiaE1hHH

Comment: What are you trying to drag where?

Comment: I want to test the dragging of an item to reorder items within a column.  Eg Drag item 1 below item 3.

Answer (score 0):

This will drag `Item 1` card from the left to the middle column:

```
browser.div(class: "card", index: 0).drag_and_drop_by(200, 0)
```

Something like this should drag `Item 1` under `Item 2` but for some reason it does not work

```
browser.div(class: "card", index: 0).drag_and_drop_on(browser.div(class: "card", index: 1))
```

More information:

- http://watir.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Element.html#drag_and_drop_by-instance_method
- http://watir.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Element.html#drag_and_drop_on-instance_method

Comment: Yes, that "for some reason it does not work" is exactly why I asked the question!!  I tried exactly that, and I couldn't get it to work either.  Any suggestions as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: I do not know why it does not work. I would suggest that you create a bug here: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues